# Slow wired connection speed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wired-networking

I have an Acer Aspire One AOA150/ZG5

I'd like to understand if the connection speed is too slow - 25/30 Mbps

Also, how can I check if something is wrong?

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS at the end of the year.

With Windows my connection speed is about 280/290 Mbps.

Comment: Connection to what? Are you sure that Ubuntu isn't reporting Megabytes per second, while Windows is reporting Megabits per second?

Comment: How is it possible to get  280/290 Mbps on Ethernet adapter when physical hardware support only 100Mbps ?

Comment: We have no idea what you're measuring or how you're measuring it.

Comment: Sorry,if I wasn't so clear.I was talking about wired download speed.I always used Speedtest and I use Acer with Ubuntu but, with Windows, I use another pc.Sorry again.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on my computer, somehow related to the IPv6 implementation.
Try this and check if there's a difference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/475493/ubuntu-14-04-lts-wired-internet-extremely-slow

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my ethernet. I checked the download speed on the Windows platform, it was showing around 1 Gbps. Then I checked on Ubuntu, and it was 6 Mbps, and the upload speed was around 500 Mbps. Trying so many solutions and not getting resolved was frustrating. Then I updated my Linux kernel from 5.0.0.32 to 5.4.0.70. Now it is working fine and the downloading speed is the same as Windows.